# finding the value pair that has the highest affinity in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Hi I am current working on a algorithm problem set.

Given the below file in a file.txt file,

```
yahoo,ap42
google,ap42
twitter,thl76
google,aa314
google,aa314
google,thl76
twitter,aa314
twitter,ap42
yahoo,aa314
```

A web server logs page views in a log file. The log file consists of one line per page view. A page view consists of page id and a user id, separated by a comma. The affinity of a pair of pages is the number of distinct users who viewed both pages. For example in the quoted log file, the affinity of yahoo and google is 2 (because ap42 viewed both and aa314 viewed both).

My requirement is to create an algorithm which will return the pair of pages with highest affinity.

Currently, I have written below code, however, right now it is not returning the pair of pages with highest affinity, any suggest of how I am modify the code to make it work? thanks. :

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("./file.txt"));
    ArrayList<String[]> logList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        logList.add(in.nextLine().split(","));
    }
    String currentPage;
    String currentUser;

    int highestCount =0;

    for (int i = 0; i < logList.size()-1; i++) {
        int affinityCount =0;
        currentPage = logList.get(i)[0];
        currentUser = logList.get(i)[1];
        for (int j = logList.size()-1; j > 0; j--) {
            if (i != j) {
                if (!currentPage.equals(logList.get(j)[0])
                        && currentUser.equals(logList.get(j)[1])) {
                    affinityCount++;
                    System.out.println("currentPage: "+currentPage+" currentUser: "+ currentUser);
                    System.out.println("logList.get(j)[0]: "+logList.get(j)[0]+" logList.get(j)[1]): "+ logList.get(j)[1]);
                    System.out.println(affinityCount);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you need only top 2 pages with highest affinity or more?

Comment: yes, I was hoping to find the top 2 pages pair that have the highest affinity. Thank you.

Comment: Do u know the size of the number of distinct webpages and user names?

Comment: Also If there is a tie, which one you output?

Answer (score 0):

Am going to write the algorithm here . You can convert that into the code.

1. Traverse the file and create a hashMap of .
2. After this traversal, you shall get the pages viewed by each user.
3. Now traverse this dataset. For each user, take out the list of pages he viewed. Make all possible combinations of pair of pages and put it in a max heap with value set to 1. If the combination exists in heap, increment the value.
   Make sure you treat - yahoo,google same as google,yahoo while comparing.
4. At the end of this, the element at top of the heap is your output.